# was $\int_{\gamma}\frac{\sin(z)}{z^3}\,dz$ calculed right?

Tags: complex-analysis

By definition $\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$, so instead the first integral, I calculated $\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^3}\,dz$ and $\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^{-iz}}{z^3}\,dz$. As $\gamma$ parametrices the unitary circle which contain $0$ (pole or order three) I used the residue theorem and obtained finally 0. Is this well done? thanks

Comment: One need not split the integral into the sum of two integrals.

Comment: @MarkViola it can be calculated directly $Res(f,0)$ by taking $\lim_{z\to0} z^3f(z)$. I mean, it will always works? I'm confused getting the theory D:

Comment: Yes, we have $$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\sin(z)}{z^3}\,dz=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{\sin(z)}{z^3}, z=0 \right)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

There's a quicker way to do it. Expand $\sin(z)$ in a Laurent series and you get that

$$ \frac{1}{z^3} \left(z - \frac{z^3}{3!} + \cdots \right).$$

you can see that there doesn't exist a power of $\frac{1}{z}$, and hence its coefficient must be zero. That is, its residue is zero. So yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: I was thinkg about it but I was unsure, don't know why, may be I'm not studying it totally right. Thank you!

Comment: $\sin(z)$ is entire. So, you can always expand it in Laurent series. In general you can always expand the a function about a point as long it is holomorphic on a punctured disk about that point, loosely speaking.

Comment: Yea, sure! I got it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem)
$$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz$$
in this case
$$f^{''}(0)=\frac{2!}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z^{3}}dz$$
and $f(z)=\sin{z}$, having $f^{''}(z)=-\sin{z} \Rightarrow f^{''}(0)=0$, thus 
$$\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z^{3}}dz=0$$

Comment: indeed, I had to (learn) use it after professor told me "we haven't seen residue theorem so you can't use it yet", hahaha.